# Oreo: Does JobService not require startForeground?

Tags: android

As a test, I removed 'startForeground(notification)' from a job service we have and it appears to still be working.

Are we not required to post a foreground notification for a job service on Android O and up?

I'm unable to find specific documentation on this.
Any reference would be wonderful.

Thank you so much

**EDIT**

For those with the same question, I've been testing this in production for a few days.  Our app has an ongoing notification and I've been starting/updating it from a job service WITHOUT a call to startForeground and have seen NO security exceptions in crashlytics.  I feel confident in saying:

**You do NOT need to call startForeground from a job service for short running tasks** (exceptions most likely apply for ongoing tasks.  My code simply makes an api call and updates the notification views)

*Thanks to 0X0nosugar and WasabiTea*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we not required to post a foreground notification for a job service on Android O and up?

After re-reading some posts on Medium ([Scheduling jobs like a pro with JobScheduler](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129), [JobIntentService for background processing on Android O](https://medium.com/til-kotlin/jobintentservice-for-background-processing-on-android-o-39535460e060)) as well as the documentation on [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes), I get the impression you aren't required to post a foreground notification.

Not having to register as foreground `Service` also makes sense, not least because you *are* doing background work with a `JobService` (that's why you have to implement `onStopJob()` to be able to cope with interruptions at all times).

Unfortunately I could not find an explicit "you don't need a foreground notification", so all of this is just circumstantial evidence.

Comment: that's my problem.  I can't find anything that says "you don't need to do X if Y".  Makes me SUPER nervous to release without doing so... but also don't want to pepper the users with unnecessary notifications

Comment: Although this answer is speculative, I've been testing a job service that posts an ongoing notification without calling startForeground have had no issues with it.  I've even released it to the store and see no security exceptions.  So it looks like your impression was correct!  Enjoy this check

Comment: @Psest328 - thanks, and if you ever find out I am wrong please let me know, same as I will edit this post if I find more facts

Answer (score 3):

> To lower the chance of these problems, Android 8.0 places limitations on what apps can do while users aren't directly
>   interacting with them. Apps are restricted in two ways:
>
> - Background Service Limitations: While an app is idle, there are limits to its use of background services. This does not apply to
>     foreground services, which are more noticeable to the user.
> - Broadcast Limitations: With limited exceptions, apps cannot use their manifest to register for implicit broadcasts. They can still
>     register for these broadcasts at runtime, and they can use the
>     manifest to register for explicit broadcasts targeted specifically at
>     their app.
>
> **In most cases, apps can work around these limitations by using
>   JobScheduler jobs**. This approach lets an app arrange to perform work
>   when the app isn't actively running, but still gives the system the
>   leeway to schedule these jobs in a way that doesn't affect the user
>   experience. Android 8.0 offers several improvements to JobScheduler
>   that make it easier to replace services and broadcast receivers with
>   scheduled jobs; for more information, see JobScheduler improvements.

The original documentation is here - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Hope this can help you